# What's the time complexity of str.count and str.index in a for loop

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm learning the time complexity of an algorithm. I couldn't figure out why the following code has time complexity of O(n).

This is from a solution for a leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/discuss/86351/Python-3-lines-beats-100-(~-60ms)-!

```
def firstUniqChar(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """

        letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        index=[s.index(le) for le in letters if s.count(le) == 1]
        return min(index) if len(index) > 0 else -1
```

I thought this algorithm has O(n^2) and here's my logic:

For each `le` in `letters`, we need to count the times `le` showed up in the `letters` from beginning to the end, and then find the index of `le` in `letters` from the beginning to the end.

We basically iterate through the `letters`, which is O(n). For each iteration, we are doing both `count`, which is O(n), and `index`, which is also O(n). So, it should be O(iteration)*(O(count) + O(index)) = O(n) * (O(n) + O(n)) = O(2n^2) => O(n^2)

What's wrong with my logic?

**Edit:**

I think I know what's wrong with my logic. The `letters` only has 26 letters so it's a constant time.

Comment: actually, iterating through letters is constant time, since the size never changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Letters` is of constant size. It's *`s`* that changes.

```py
index = []
for le in letters: # O(1)
  if s.count(le) == 1: # count is O(n)
    index.push(s.index(le)) # index is O(n)
```

It's actually O(2n), or O(n).

Comment: If letters is constant size, then it's O(N)